# How to fetch values from model class to text fields , if only single data in json?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

this is my JSON response

```
{
"building_name": "Belsalah",
"location": "Palm",
"unit_number": "101",
"unit_type": "FLAT",
"sub_type": "1BHK",
}
```

this is how I am calling API

```
Future<UnitModel> getUnitDetails(String propertyId,String unitId,String tokenKey) async{
final response = await http.get(Constants.BASEURL + propertyId + unitId,
headers:{"Accept": "application/json",
"Authorization": tokenKey});
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  return UnitModel.fromjson(json.decode(response.body));
} else {
  throw Exception('Failed to load post');
}
}
```

this is my model class

```
class UnitModel {
 String building_name;
 String location;
 String unti_no;
 String unit_type;
 String sub_type;
 });
  factory UnitModel.fromjson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return UnitModel(
      building_name: json['building_name'],
      location: json['location'],
      unti_no: json['unit_number'],
      unit_type: json['unit_type'],
     );
    }
   }
```

How to get the model class values to the textview? [image]in a flutter page?

Comment: Just Create getter setter in your model class and call it in your activity,

Answer (score 1):

Use a FutureBuilder. Show a progress loader when the data is not loaded. When the data is loaded replace the data with your layout. When the data is loaded, you can access your data using 'className.property'.

```dart
FutureBuilder(
  future: getUnitDetails("pass","your","parameters"),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      // replace Text() with your layout.
      return Text('${snapshot.data.location} ${snapshot.data.building_name}')
    } else if (snapshot.hasError){
      // handle error.
    } else {
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
    }
  },
);
```